# Charging IC for a 1S or 3S Li-ion battery

Tags: pcb, battery-charging, lithium-ion, buck-boost, battery-monitor

I have quite specific problem; I'm designing a PCB for my robot, that is used the main board for controlling motors, gathering data from sensors, etc.
The whole PCB will be designed as a Raspberry Pi Zero HAT.
I'm using RP2040 as the controlling chip, PWM generator and as a bus for a set of I2C sensor modules.

The problem I'm facing now is that I need to be able to connect a 1S Li-Ion battery OR 3S Li-ion battery as a power source for the robot (I need the circuit to work with either of them, because I'll be using different motors). I want to charge the 1S battery from my PCB (through USB C cable), but not the 3S battery (because I don't want to / don't have place for balancing circuit). But I want the charger to work as battery-monitor and protection (overvoltage/undervoltage/current) for both batteries.

I've searched through these TI ICs: [Texas Instruments - charger-ICs](https://www.ti.com/power-management/battery-management/charger-ics/products.html)
but there are just too many of them and I don't know, if I could somehow configure them, to work the way I described?

I also need stabilized 5 V (for RPi Zero 2 W) and 3.3 V (for the rest). I know there are some 2 channel buck-boost converters, but I just can't choose one...

So could anyone recommend me some charging ICs and/or buck-boost converters?

Comment: Li-poly batteries are a type of li-ion cell, so your problem is really just how to power your board from both 1S and 3S battery configurations and distinguish between them.

Comment: @Hearth Yes, thanks, i know that these cells are almost the same, I guess I was just unnecessarily specific.